# How to pass a data retreived over udp connection from child to parent in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, udp

I am new to react native and working with a project that requires data from another external device over a udp connection. I received data without any problems, but I want to render this data by passing it to the parent component. if anyone can help, that will be very useful.

```
 console.log("UdpHandlerRtDisplay constructor called")
 
 this.socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4')

 this.socket.on('listening', () => {
    const address = this.socket.address();
    console.log(`Listening to ${address.address}: ${address.port}`)
 });

 this.socket.on('message',function (msg) {
  console.log('message received',msg)
})
 this.socket.bind(8888)}
```

I want to get the data(msg) outside the function.And also I want to know how to pass it to parent component.

Answer (score 0):

In React, information normally flows from parent to child. Did you consider declaring the socket in the parent component? You could then have the `socket.on('message'....)` code in the parent component, where you need the data.

One problem with that approach may be that you don't have everything you need to start the socket listening when the parent component is mounting - you may want it to listen only in response to some future event. To overcome this you could pass the socket down as a prop to the child where you *do* have the necessary info, and call `.bind()` in response to the triggering event, from within the child component.